# How to make carrierwave delete the file when destroying a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm using the carrierwave gem to upload files.

I have built a system for users to flag images as inappropriate and for admins to remove the images. From what I can tell, calling destroy on the image will only remove the path name from the table.

Is there a way to have carrierwave actually remove the file itself? Or should rails automatically remove the file when I destroy the image path?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Not sure what CarrierWave offers for this, but you could use `FileUtils` in the Ruby standard library with an ActiveRecord callback.

For instance,

```
require 'FileUtils'
before_destroy :remove_hard_image

def remove_hard_image
  FileUtils.rm(path_to_image)
end
```

Sidenote: This code is from memory.

Comment: There's also [`File#delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M000018) in the core clases.

Comment: `require  'fileutils'` if you don't want to get all kinds of warnings about constants.

Comment: Using a gem for something straight forward like this, esp. which the stdlib offers this seem unnecessary.  +1 to File#delete

Comment: @yekta [`fileutils.rb` is part of the Ruby Standard Library](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/fileutils.rb).

Comment: Oh, huh.  IIRC I was looking in the docs and didn't see it. Thanks for point that out.

Answer (score 102):

Like @mu_is_too_short said, you can use *[File#delete](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-delete)*.

Here's a code snippet you could use as a helper with a little tweaking in your rails app.

```
def remove_file(file)
  File.delete(file)
end
```

or if you just have the filename stored in **file**

```
def remove_file(file)
  File.delete("./path/to/#{file}")
end
```

Comment: what is the difference between File#delete and FileUtils.rm?

Comment: in 2.2.2 it looks like `File.delete` will take filename(s) as individual arguments and will return an Integer of the number of files removed. It will also raise an exception on any error. `FileUtils.rm` takes a list , or string, of filename(s) and can also be passed options like `:force => true` which will not raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

If one wants to delete a file but does not want to specify the full filename you can use the below.

Can also be used to delete many files or all files in a directory with a specific extension...

```
file = Rails.root.join("tmp", "foo*")
```

or

```
file = Rails.root.join("tmp", ".pdf")
```

---

```
files = Dir.glob(file) #will build an array of the full filepath & filename(s)
files.each do |f|
  File.delete(f)
end
```